# Oracle - How to *correctly* convert from EST/EDT to GMT?

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, timezone

I have a query that is doing some time zone conversions. As an example, I want to convert from an `EST` time to `GMT`:

For the EDT time of `3/13/2016 @2:00 AM` (immediately following the EST->EDT changeover) I should get a GMT time of `3/13/2016 7:00:00 AM`  ([verified here](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/est-to-gmt-converter) for the date of 3/13/2016 @2am). Instead I am getting `3/13/2016 6:00:00 AM` from using this query:

```
SELECT NEW_TIME(TO_DATE('2016/3/13 02:00:00 AM', 
               'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS AM'),'EDT','GMT') 
FROM DUAL;
```

For the EST time of `3/13/2016 @1:00AM` (one second before the changeover) I am getting what appears to be the correct result:

```
SELECT NEW_TIME(TO_DATE('2016/3/13 01:59:59 AM', 
                        'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS AM'),'EST','GMT') 
FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
3/13/2016 6:59:59 AM
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have read the Oracle documentation on NEW_TIME and have tried switching the EDT/EST with the GMT (based on the one example they have at the bottom of the page) but that gives me even more odd results.

Comment: Actually, I see exactly what is going on here, I can't believe it took me this long to figure it out. 2:00am on 3/13/2016 DOES NOT EXIST in `EPT` time! You would never see 2am on your clock on this day! We just skip to 3am... (Man I hate daylight savings time!)

Comment: You should be using the fully qualified location identifier, `America/New_York`

Comment: It doesn't appear that this is an issue for you here but make sure that you're up to date on the database time zone patches if you're working with time zone data particularly if you have data from time zones around the world rather than just a handful of US time zones.  Lots of production databases aren't up to date with all the wrinkles about things like when DST starts in various locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the old fashion function `NEW_TIME`, use [FROM_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions068.htm#SQLRF00644) and [Datetime Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions007.htm#SQLRF00401) as recommended by Oracle.

One problem is time time zones `EST` or `EDT` **do not have** any daylight saving! `EST` always means (most likely) UTC-05:00 no matter if summer of winter. `EDT` always means (most likely) UTC-04:00 no matter if summer of winter.

Apart from missing daylight saving support, `EST` or `EDT` are ambiguous, see this list:

```
SELECT tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzname), tzname
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
WHERE tzname IN ('EST', 'EDT') OR tzabbrev IN ('EST', 'EDT')
ORDER BY 1,2;

TZABBREV    TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)   TZNAME
===============================================
EDT -04:00  America/Detroit
EDT -04:00  US/Eastern
EDT -04:00  US/East-Indiana
EDT -04:00  EST5EDT
EDT -04:00  Canada/Eastern
EDT -04:00  America/Toronto
EDT -04:00  America/Thunder_Bay
EDT -04:00  America/Santo_Domingo
EDT -04:00  America/Pangnirtung
EDT -04:00  America/Nipigon
EDT -04:00  America/New_York
EDT -04:00  America/Nassau
EDT -04:00  America/Montreal
EDT -04:00  America/Louisville
EDT -04:00  America/Kentucky/Monticello
EDT -04:00  America/Kentucky/Louisville
EDT -04:00  America/Iqaluit
EDT -04:00  America/Indianapolis
EDT -04:00  America/Indiana/Winamac
EDT -04:00  America/Indiana/Vincennes
EDT -04:00  America/Indiana/Vevay
EDT -04:00  America/Indiana/Petersburg
EDT -04:00  America/Indiana/Marengo
EDT -04:00  US/Michigan
EDT -04:00  America/Fort_Wayne
EDT -04:00  America/Grand_Turk
EDT -04:00  America/Indiana/Indianapolis
EDT -05:00  America/Jamaica
EDT -05:00  America/Indiana/Tell_City
EDT -05:00  Jamaica
EDT -05:00  America/Cancun
EDT -05:00  America/Port-au-Prince
EST +09:30  Australia/Broken_Hill
EST +09:30  Australia/Yancowinna
EST +10:00  Australia/Canberra
EST +10:00  Australia/Brisbane
EST +10:00  Australia/ACT
EST +10:00  Australia/Currie
EST +10:00  Australia/Hobart
EST +10:00  Australia/Lindeman
EST +10:00  Australia/Melbourne
EST +10:00  Australia/NSW
EST +10:00  Australia/Queensland
EST +10:00  Australia/Tasmania
EST +10:00  Australia/Sydney
EST +10:00  Australia/Victoria
EST +10:30  Australia/Lord_Howe
EST +10:30  Australia/LHI
EST +11:00  Antarctica/Macquarie
EST -03:00  America/Moncton
EST -04:00  America/Antigua
EST -04:00  America/Detroit
EST -04:00  America/Fort_Wayne
EST -04:00  America/Grand_Turk
EST -04:00  America/Indiana/Indianapolis
EST -04:00  America/Indiana/Marengo
EST -04:00  America/Indiana/Petersburg
EST -04:00  America/Indiana/Vevay
EST -04:00  America/Indiana/Vincennes
EST -04:00  America/Indiana/Winamac
EST -04:00  America/Indianapolis
EST -04:00  America/Iqaluit
EST -04:00  America/Kentucky/Louisville
EST -04:00  America/Kentucky/Monticello
EST -04:00  America/Louisville
EST -04:00  America/Montreal
EST -04:00  America/Nassau
EST -04:00  America/New_York
EST -04:00  America/Nipigon
EST -04:00  America/Pangnirtung
EST -04:00  America/Santo_Domingo
EST -04:00  America/Thunder_Bay
EST -04:00  America/Toronto
EST -04:00  Canada/Eastern
EST -04:00  EST5EDT
EST -04:00  US/East-Indiana
EST -04:00  US/Eastern
EST -04:00  US/Michigan
EST -05:00  US/Central
EST -05:00  Jamaica
EST -05:00  America/Cancun
EST -05:00  America/Cayman
EST -05:00  America/Chicago
EST -05:00  America/Coral_Harbour
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Knox
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Tell_City
EST -05:00  America/Jamaica
EST -05:00  America/Knox_IN
EST -05:00  America/Atikokan
EST -05:00  America/Menominee
EST -05:00  America/Merida
EST -05:00  America/Panama
EST -05:00  America/Port-au-Prince
EST -05:00  America/Rankin_Inlet
EST -05:00  America/Resolute
EST -05:00  CST
EST -05:00  EST
EST -05:00  US/Indiana-Starke
EST -06:00  America/Managua
EST -06:00  America/Cambridge_Bay
```

Try it like this, then your times will automatically converted properly regardless of your seasons:

```
SELECT 
    FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2016/January/01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY/MONTH/DD HH:MI:SS AM'), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
    FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2016/July/01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY/MONTH/DD HH:MI:SS AM'), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
FROM dual;
```

Comment: In most every case I would recommend people use your answer, but I was directed to use a little different solution (my answer). If it were completely up to me I just would have used the `FROM_TZ()` function as per your recommendation. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using:

```
SELECT SYSDATE+(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR'),2,2))/24  
FROM DUAL;
```

where `(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR'),2,2))` provides you with the current offset from utc time. I agree that `FROM_TZ` is probably more accurate in the many edge cases that exist with timezone but we were really looking for something that would calculate quickly when embedding this into a view.

To properly convert between zones, I simply added the current offset to whatever time it was that I needed to convert:

```
DECLARE 
l_convert_me_to_utc DATE := TO_DATE('9/12/2016 1:00:00 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
l_converted DATE;
BEGIN
    l_converted:=(l_convert_me_to_utc+(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR'),2,2))/24);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('UTC TIME IS: '||TO_CHAR(l_converted, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'));    
END;

UTC TIME IS: 09/12/2016 05:00:00 PM
```

Which makes sense since right now I am in NY TZ in EDT with a -4 offset from UTC

EDIT: As per the comments below, this really only works if you are converting whatever your OS SYSDATE is right now to UTC. If it's some other timezone or some time in the past or future this does not really work. My final logic was more complex than what you see above. For my application and with more complex logic (checking a table with all TZ switch dates from now till 2100), this really DOES work. Just don't take what I have above and assume it converts things to UTC perfectly as is.

Comment: No - sorry.  You cannot assume that the *current* offset is the correct offset for the point in time you're working with.  That is a leading source of data errors when it comes to time zone conversions.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  You need to use `America/New_York` to properly represent all states and transitions of the Eastern Time zone in the USA.  Consider that though the current offset in NY is -4, if the date you were converting was in December (for example), that the correct offset would be -5.

Comment: (Also, you said +4, that would be applicable in parts of Russia and the Middle East.  You mean -4)

Comment: Be aware, `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns the time in the time zone of database operating system time zone. May times this changes twice a year due to day light saving time! (At least I have seen this behavior on many servers). Consider also function [SYS_EXTRACT_UTC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions186.htm#SQLRF06119) to get time in UTC.

Comment: Function `l_convert_me_to_utc+(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR'),2,2))/24` works only if the time zone of database operating system  is set like `03:00`. It will fail when it is set like `UTC` or `GMT` or `America/New_York`. or ... - you can do that if you like to do so.